# How to remove an unused column from RECORD from schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I have column name inside RECORD data named paymentMethod but I need now it renamed to payment_method.
How can I remove or rename column of RECORD?

```
ALTER TABLE dataset.table RENAME COLUMN data.paymentMethod TO data.payment_method;
```

not works because of error `ALTER TABLE RENAME COLUMN not found: paymentMethod at [13:46]`

Renaming column in schema.json and calling command from CLI

```
bq update projectID:dataset.table schema.json
```

not works because of error: `Field data.paymentMethod is missing in new schema`

No way? No answer in official docs here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#deleting_a_column_from_a_table_schema

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CREATE OR REPLACE statement to recreate the table with the existing data with the new schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset.table`
AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(data), --exclude column to be changed
  STRUCT(
    data.paymentMethod AS payment_method, --renamed struct attribute
    data.payment_amount
  ) AS data
FROM `dataset.table`
```

If the struct column is repeated (array) it would look a little different

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset.table`
AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(data),
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      paymentMethod AS payment_method,
      payment_amount
    FROM table.data
  ) AS data
FROM `dataset.table`
```